# how to start with crystal report with phpmyadmin?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, database-connection

so i am using `visual studio community 2015` and a `phpmyadmin version 10.1.21-MariaDB` the problem is connecting `crystal report version 13.0.18.2192` when i follow these steps http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm
i got stuck on `connection information` specifically on determining the `server` for the combobx does not contain anything and for that reason i went and do a little research that `server` and `hostname` is basically the same so i chose the `localhost` as my server but when i clicked on finish my `visual studios` froze and still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MariaDB is not natively supported by Crystal Reports, you will need to install and configure an ODBC driver first.

For ODBC driver, download from: https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/

After the driver is installed, go to Admin Tools > ODBC Administrator and [create a new System DSN for MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/).

> **Connection parameters**
>
> When configuring a DSN you can use the following keywords:
>
> - **DSN:** Name of the DSN
> - **Driver:** The name of the MariaDB ODBC Driver. Must always be {MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver}
> - **Server:** name or IP of the MariaDB database server. Aliases: Servername
> - **User:** user name for database authentication. Aliases: UID,
> - **Password:** password for database authentication. Aliases: PWD
> - **Database:** default database. Aliases: DB
> - **Port:** TCP/IP Port of the database server
> - **Option:** For MySQL Connector/ODBC compatibility. Aliases: Options

After you install and configure, point to the data source in Crystal Reports.

Comment: sorry for the late reply my computer crashed and took me for a while to get it up and running and i'm currently establishing the connection but the problem is i don't have odbc administrator in my admin tools is t okay to use the odbc datasource instead?

Comment: I think so. The name might vary by os version. You should see a user Dsn tab and system dsn tab. What is are you using and is it 32-but or 64-bit?

Comment: windows 10 64-bit i followed the connection parameter you gave then this form requesting for statement(s), connection timeout in sec and connection character set what values do i these and do i check any of the following: enabling automatic reconnecting, use compression, don't prompt when connecting

Comment: If your MariaDB environment was configured with defaults, then your DSN parameters should be defaults as well. I'd try not checking anything on or off and see how it goes?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change server address from "localhost" to the loop IP address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Surely localhost will simple redirect to 127.0.0.1 though?

Comment: Yes but the problem could be in database in interpretation of this system environment variable.

Comment: Of course it make a difference. The first difference is granted privileges in Your data base. Others may get localhost and the other loop address 127.0.0.1. The second one is under Unix operating system -  when You use localhost You are referring to the Unix socket not to the much slower TCP/IP.